# Displaying Content based on object number

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have been trying to display content in a PDF in an indexed manner, such that when I give a object number, the corresponding content should be displayed.

I am using pdfbox v1.8.10 for the same. I have been able to get the total no of objects and the object list, but still cant get the content associated with the objects.

Any pointers would be great.

Thanks

```
PDFParser pdfParserObj = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(name));

        pdfParserObj.parse();


        COSDocument documentObject = pdfParserObj.getDocument();

        /*
         * To identify which object is the Catalog Object
         */

        COSObject catalogObject = documentObject.getCatalog();

        System.out.println("Catalog object : " );
        System.out.println(catalogObject);

        /*
         * To display total no of objects in the PDF
         */
        List<COSObject> objects = documentObject.getObjects();

        System.out.println("No of objetcs in the document : " );
        System.out.println(objects.size());


        System.out.println("the list");

        documentObject.print();
```

I have tried using the List's get(int) method, but it displays the object only.

i.e. 
COSObject{2, 0}

Comment: Use the `List`'s get(int) method to access by index.

Comment: The PDF objects in general do not make sense without a context. E.g. a content stream may represent something completely differently if associated with a different page with entirely different tm resource definitions.

Comment: Call the getObject() method of the COSObject object. However I doubt you'll become happy with it. For example, if you then have a COSDIctionary, will you know what it is about? I suspect you have a completely different question.

Comment: To understand more about PDF, maybe try the PDFDebugger. Get the "debugger app" at http://pdfbox.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr Thank you, I'll use that and see.

Comment: To learn how to do specific things with PDFBox, have also a look at the many examples in the source code download.